# Form a distance matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm given a 20*122 matrix p. Each row of matrix is a 20-dim vector. I want to calculate the distance between each vector and form a distance matrix. Here's my code

```
mul = []
for i in 1:size(p,1)
    push!(mul,norm(p[1,:]-p[i,:]))
end
mul = transpose(tiedrank(mul))
for i in 2:size(p,1)
    for j in 1:size(p,1)
        mul2 = []
        push!(mul2,norm(p[i,:]-p[j,:]))
    end
    mul = vcat(mul,tiedrank(mul2)')
end
mul
```

I got the error that

> UndefVarError: mul2 not defined

How to fix this code?

Comment: Your code will be super slow, even if you can make it run. Untyped containers (`mul = []`) are slow, iterative `push!` is slow, iterative `vcat` is slow, slices are slow, and operating along rows is slow, since Julia arrays are _column major_. Worst of all, working in global scope is _super slow_, make a function instead. I think it is fair to say that your code is very nearly as inefficient as theoretically possible

Comment: @DNF -- You forgot the final QED. Funniest proof I saw in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Distances.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl) package:

```
julia> using Distances

julia> p = rand(20, 122)
20×122 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.830266   0.938016  …  0.919852  0.549327
 0.337624   0.863166     0.917122  0.601121
 ⋮                    ⋱  ⋮
 0.122402   0.85733      0.111437  0.694836
 0.0791678  0.763321     0.968744  0.279512

julia> pairwise(Euclidean(), p)
122×122 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0      2.21042  …  1.58048  1.94589
 2.21042  0.0         1.71839  1.95506
 ⋮                 ⋱  ⋮
 1.58048  1.71839  …  0.0      1.73247
 1.94589  1.95506     1.73247  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice features of Julia is that you can copy-paste an efficient algorithm from [a paper](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Ealbanie/notes/Euclidean_distance_trick.pdf) and get it working in a 1-to-1 lines of code.

[image]

Here is how you might write that in Julia:

```
p = rand(20, 122);
G = p * p';
D = sqrt.(diag(G) .+ diag(G)' .- 2 .* G);
```

This is exactly what you get if you use a package like [Distances.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl),

```
using Distances
D = pairwise(Euclidean(), p')
```

Note that I used `p = p'` in both methods because you wanted the distance between row vectors.

Comment: Remember the dot in front of the minus sign, and also dot the multiplication: `sqrt.(diag(G) .+ diag(G)' .- 2 .* G)`. Otherwise you get unnecessary allocation of temporary matrices.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just copying the algorithm without paying attention to performance at all. It makes a speed difference of about 12% with 40% less allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You define `mul2` inside the loop. Move the definition one line earlier.